# ¿Cómo trabajar los datos obtenidos con fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

¿Como hago para trabajar con datos obtenidos por `fetch` en una función aparte?

```
function getAjax(id){

  return fetch (`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/`)
    .then(function(response) {
           return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(pokemon) {

        console.log(pokemon);
        return pokemon;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message);
      });
}
```

En este obtengo los datos y todo bien, pero cuando quiero trabajar con ellos en otra solo obtengo la promesa, entonces ¿como saco los datos de la promesa?.

Esta es la función que se supone trabaja los datos.

```
function addPokemon(){
    let i=0;
  //  let pokemon;
    let contenedor=document.getElementById("pokemones");
    var numbersPokemon= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,123,212,213];
    var htmlcontenedor
    htmlcontenedor="<div class='container'>";
    htmlcontenedor+="<div class='row'>";
    numbersPokemon.forEach(element => {
      const pokemon=getAjax(element);
       // console.log(pokemon);
        htmlcontenedor+="<div class='col'>";
        //htmlcontenedor+=element;
        htmlcontenedor+=pokemon;
        htmlcontenedor+="</div>";
        i++;
        if(i%3==0){
            htmlcontenedor+="</div>";
            htmlcontenedor+="<div class='row'>";
        }

    });
    htmlcontenedor+="</div>";
    htmlcontenedor+="</div>";
    contenedor.innerHTML+=htmlcontenedor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como tu has dicho con la función `getAjax` devuelve una promesa y lo único que te faltaría es llamar al método `then` para obtener los datos.

```js
function getAjax(id) {

    return fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/`)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(pokemon) {

            return pokemon;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message);
        });
}
//Usamos then para esperar los valores
getAjax(1).then(function(pokemon) {
    //Aqui ya puedes procesar los datos...
    console.log(pokemon)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es un problema muy habitual cuando empezamos a trabajar con [fetch](https://www.todojs.com/api-fetch-el-nuevo-estandar-que-permite-hacer-llamadas-http/), se nos olvida que devuelve una promesa, no los datos como tal. Cuando en el último de los .then() hacemos un retorno, este se utiliza como resultado de la promesa que devolvió fetch. Es un poco confuso al principio, pero cuando uno empieza a dominar las promesas todo se vuelve mucho más sencillo.